# Laravel - Jobs can't connect to database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am using some chained jobs in laravel, but suddenly they stopped working, in the log I can see that all the problems are connection problems, starting with

```
 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(638):
Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select `section...', Array, Object(Closure))
```

In the console I do not receive any error, however, there is the job that is repeated and it tries again because the database rejected the connection, where can I check or set a correct connection of the jobs with the database?

The rest of my application works totally normal.

My queue.php file [looks like this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/queue.php), but without line 84

Comment: I would check the settings in `/config/queue.php` for `connections` and the related ENV values if they are used in those settings and go from there

Comment: do you use queue workers for your jobs? I mean something like supervisor->queue_worker

Comment: @WesleySmith I updated my question with the file

Comment: @Ray yes I'm using workers